# how to get docs after specific date time?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I want to get documents from a collection after a specific date time.

Example:

if the date = 30/11/2020, 12:30AM (in javascript)

1. The query should return documents created after the above date.
2. The query should not return documents created before the above date.

You can see my current code:

```
await db
    .collection(`users/${user}/messages`)
    .orderBy("cDate", "desc") /* {cDate: firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())}*/
    .limit(100)
    .get();
```

Any help

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do here, since we can't see the data in your documents.  But you will need to use a where clause to filter the documents in the query according to your needs.  If you need help with this, you should edit the question to explain in more detail the actual contents of your documents, and what you've tried to do to filter them, as you see in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators

Comment: @DougStevenson, I think it is clear, I just want to return documents after a specific date. exampe: after 30/11/2020 12:00AM. So my query should return all docs if they are created after this date and should not return those documents after before this date

Comment: Do you have a date property in your documents?

Comment: question edited please have a look at it again

Comment: @AndresGardiol, Yes I have it as you can see `cDate `

Comment: We need to see the type of data in the documents.  Are they timestamps? Integers with unix epoch offset?  Strings of some sort?  Without knowing specifically what's in the documents, it's not possible to build a query for it.  A screenshot of actual documents to match would help.

Comment: @DougStevenson, `{cDate: firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())}`

Comment: Yeah, that's information that should be in the question itself for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const isoDateTime = '2020-11-30T12:30:00';
await db
    .collection(`users/${user}/messages`)
    .where('cDate', '>=', isoDate);  //<--- Its important to have an ISO formatted date string
    .orderBy("cDate", "desc")
    .limit(100)
    .get();
```

With this you should get all the documents after the `isoDate` (included).
You can use `>` to not include the date

Comment: thank you very much, and here is `cDate` is firestore date will it works ?

Comment: In your firestore documents you should have an ISO DateTime string in your `cDate` properties

Comment: thank you, I will return back after checking your answer, if it works then will be accepted

Comment: You can see more information about the `where` method here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators

Comment: Could you please let me know why ISO date is important ?

Comment: Because you are comparing strings, and ISO Date format let you compare string dates with `<`,`>` and `==` operators. 
You can see this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327580/is-direct-comparison-of-javascript-iso-date-strings-safe

Comment: .where("cDate", ">", new Date("11/12/2019")), is not working, Could you please help me what is the problem .... ?

Comment: `new Date("11/12/2019")` is an Object, you need to compare a string. You could do `new Date("11/12/2019").toISOString()`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/toISOString to read more about that method

Comment: I just put as an example the real code is: where("cDate", ">", new Date(new Date(). toISOString()))

Comment: Please once again see it here is firestore query so i can't change the `where("cDate", ..)

Comment: `new Date(new Date(). toISOString())` is still an object, it is not a string. `new Date()` returns a Date object.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to filter the documents based on a timestamp type field, you can simply provide a JavaScript date object as a filter on that field.

```
.where("cDate", ">", aJavaScriptDateObject)
```

You can also use a Firestore [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) object as well.

Comment: will it be supported by any date object ?

Comment: example: new Data().toISOString()

Comment: No, that's a string, not a date object.

Comment: Is that possible to save in firestore as {cDate: new Date()}. if yes will still `orderBy` works ?

Comment: That also saves a timestamp that can be ordered with other timestamps.

Comment: .where("cDate", ">", new Date("11/12/2019")), is not working, Could you please help me what is the problem

Comment: You can't pass any string you want to the Date constructor.  Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to figure out what you can do to create a new Date object.  If you're still having problems, ask a new question to explain what's not working the way you expect.

Comment: It is actually this: `.where("cDate", ">", new Date(new Date(). toISOString()))`